# Backbone collection.create and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, promise

Im currently implementing a Purchase Order type View. Where I have a PurchaseOrder table and a PurchaseOrderLine table for the items. The first thing I do when the use presses the **save** button I first save the Purchase Order and then I retrieve the PurchaseOrderID and save to each individual PurchaseOrder item. The problems is the following:

```
Promise.resolve( app.PurchaseOrder.create(formData) ).then(function(response){
                purchaseOrderID = response.collection.models[0].attributes.id;
                for(var key in formLineData){
                    if(formLineData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        formLineData[key]['requestID'] = purchaseOrderID;
                        app.PurchaseOrderLines.create(formLineData[key]);
                    }
                }
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
```

**formData** is the PurchaseOrder data, **formLineData** is the PurchaseOrderLine Data(I do the **for** loop to insert requestIDs to all items).

I am using a Promise because collection.fetch does not return a promise on Backbone(I think my implementation isn't quite correct because Promise.resolve() is use to make thenables a promise and in this case it isn't). The problem is that when the **save** button is clicked the **then** part passes even PurchaseOrder hasn't been created. So when it gets to the PurchaseOrderLine.create, all the items are saved without a PurchaseOrderID. I have two options:

1. Add a server validation for this. The problem with this is that everytime is going to return an error and this can be bothersome to the user.
2. Add a setTimeout to at least wait a couple seconds for the write to over on the server.

Could please shed a light on this topic.

Comment: If the then() fires even when the ajax call in create isn't done, I would suggest that app.PurchaseOrder.create() does NOT return a promise.  non-Promise objects are considered resolved.

Comment: fetch does return a promise object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967191/why-doesnt-backbone-collection-fetch-return-a-promise

Comment: I did not use fetch, its **create**

Comment: first of all you should [edit] and update your question to clarify that your issue is not with `fetch`. `create` immediately returns the created model. If you want to wait for the server till adding the created model to collection and then do something, pass `{wait: true}`

Comment: Already corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```js
app.PurchaseOrder.create(formData).then(function (response) {
  var purchaseOrderID = response.collection.models[0].attributes.id;

  return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
    for (var key in formLineData) {
      if (formLineData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        formLineData[key]["requestID"] = purchaseOrderID;
        await app.PurchaseOrderLines.create(formLineData[key]);
      }
    }
    resolve()
  });
});
```

or maybe doing something like this using Promise.all

```js
Promise.all(formLineData.map(()=>app.PurchaseOrderLines.create(formLineData[key])))
```